# Is it better to put script code in the page bottom or in third party library's dom ready function?

Tags: performance, optimization, web

I want make my website to load faster, usually I put my code in the `<head>`, in some third party library's dom ready function, like jQuery.

I read that if I put the script code directly in the bottom, it could make the page load more faster.

So if its true, It means that If I put the script in the bottom its better right?

Comment: you mean putting the JS files at the end of the `<body>`, before the end tag?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: before the `<body>` or the `<html>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Loading a script causes the browser to block loading the rest of the page until the script is loaded and executed. This is to allow the code to make any changes before the browser continues rendering. Placing your scripts at the bottom of the page (just before the `</body>` tag) allows the browser to load an rednder substantially all of the document before it blocks to load the scripts. From the users perspective the page will load more quickly.

This is not the same as controlling execution by adding your code in a DOMReady function, although in practice there may be little difference in effect.

Comment: Agree, nowadays network speed is fast & more contents are in CDN / cached (such as jQuery, as it is widely used). The difference is not that significant.